# First hat-trick in T-20 international

Tags: cricket, trivia

Who is the first bowler to take hat-trick in T-20 international?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brett Lee is the first bowler to take a hat-trick in T20I matches. He took against Bangladesh at Cape Town in World T20 2007. See [the scoreboard](http://www.espncricinfo.com/twenty20wc/engine/match/287866.html).

From [the match report](http://www.espncricinfo.com/twenty20wc/content/story/311247.html):

> #### Another Twenty20 first
>
> After the first Twenty20 century, by Chris Gayle against South Africa, this match brought **the first hat-trick in the international version. Brett Lee was the man** with the honour as his pace proved too much for the middle order...

Here is the list of [the hat-trick in T20I matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283738.html).